# does Panel.Visible=false don't add to DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, dom

I have a .aspx where in I am adding couple of panels dynamically from code behind. I want to show or hide them based on certain conditions. so I am using.

```
Panel P1=new Panel();
Panel P2=new Panel();
P1.Visible=P2.Visible=false;
if(//Panel1 condition is true)
P1.Visible=true;
if(//Panel2 condition is true)
    P2.Visible=true;
```

Now when I look at DOM in developer tools, there is no mark up for corresponding hidden panel. All I see is only visible panel's mark up.
I thought `.Visible=false` will add `display:none` to style of element and `.Visible=true` will add `display:block` to style of element, so I can use javascript to do some DOM manipulation as needed. Was my understanding wrong or what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Server side objects Visible=false removes their Html codes from rendering

To have it CSS Visible=false:

Use:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel panel = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel();
panel.Style["display"] = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

`.Visible=false` code will not render the element on client side. You will not have access to this elements on dom.

To use element on client side use class or html style property

Like: create class hidden like below

```
.hidden
{
display:none;
}
```

Use this class and add in panel then it will be accessible in DOM as well.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to take away from this early gotcha, is the difference between server- and client rendered content.

Asp.Net will interpret your elements in your HTML driven .aspx-document, and render specific elements such as panel, calendar, button, textbox into divs, a lot of divs with buttons, a button and inputfield/textarea.

If you were to hide an element, in the client, with a quick and dirty "*display: none*", the element would be hidden to the visitor of the page, but you could still get to it via the DOM. In the same way is the element you have selected to be hidden using "visible=false", is hidden to the user. This is done by not printing the element in the requested HTML, but you're still able to get to that element from the server side code.

Serverside is all about sending as little data as possible. Why would the server ever need to send HTML that would never to shown.